# How to read dynamic controller actions

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a standard very simple magento module and a simple `IndexController` with an `showAction()` and everything works fine.

My Book table in database

```
id   |   key                 | status

1    | fifty_shades_of_grey  | 1
```

current frontend link:

```
domain.com/book/index/show/592
```

and this works great.

but I want to use something like:

```
domain.com/book/fifty_shades_of_grey
```

I guess, I need some rewrites or Routers but I don't know where to begin.

Can someone show me the right way how to do it?

I have tried something like this: (But not working...)

```
<rewrite>
    <Ravi_Book>
      <to><![CDATA[#^/book/index/show/id/([-\0-9.]+)?$#]]></to>
      <from><![CDATA[/book/$1]]></from>
      <complete>1</complete>
    </Ravi_Book>
</rewrite>
```

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: Yes, you have to create your own custom router. You can find help over http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/ .

Comment: @gulshan Thank you. I will check it now but I think there must be simple solutions in 1.9+, because this blog has been written in Aug 23, 2012